# Django ,View class,There are two put methods

Tags: django

environment: django==1.11.11, rest_framework

Having methods with the same name handle different routes in the same view class or view set, using the decorator ?

example:

```
class Indexs(APIView):

    @decorator("detailed/")
    def get(self, request):
        pass

    @decorator("list/")
    def get(self, request):
        pass
```

# supplemental

I want to handle two GET requests in the same view class. One GET request details, the other request list content, but the same name request is overwritten

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from indexs import views

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'category/$', views.Indexs.as_view()),
    url(r'list/$', views.Indexs.as_view()),
    url(r'detailed/$', views.Indexs.as_view()),
]
```

views.py

```
class Indexs(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({"list": "list"})

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({"detailed": "detailed"})
```

http://127.0.0.1/list  and  http://127.0.0.1/detailed
Return results are all

```
{
    "detailed": "detailed"
}
```

but i want

http://127.0.0.1/list Return results

```
{
    "list": "list"
}
```

http://127.0.0.1/detailed

```
{
    "detailed": "detailed"
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't much clear. Can you add more details?

Comment: I want to handle two GET requests in the same view class. One GET request details, the other request list content, but the same name request is overwritten

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:12345/list/ and http://127.0.0.1:12345/detailed/, Return results are all 

```
{
    "detailed": "detailed"
}
```

Comment: Dont add code snippet to comment section, edit your question and add the snippet

Comment: What is `@decorator`?

Comment: AKX :    I remember where I saw a decorator that could be solved in a similar way. Grammatical sugar

Answer (score 0):

Learn more about implementing class based views in [django rest framewrok documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/) it's pretty much straight forward. Django Rest Framework makes it easy to write DRY code with built in Generic views.

For example,an in built [generic view](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) like `ListCreateAPIView` below will perform `GET` and `POST` Http methods.

You can get a list of snippets and snippet detail from your urls:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.SnippetList.as_view()),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SnippetDetail.as_view()),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class SnippetAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
```

Comment: These are two types of requests.I want to use the same request method

Comment: Then you can have one view for `SnippeListAPIView` and the other for `SnippetDetailAPIView`. In my opinion it's better that way, Imagine in a situation you will need to add `put` ,`post` and `delete` you could simply add them in the `SnippetDetailAPIView`.

Comment: I know this can be done, but I need to create multiple view in one python file.It would be perfect if you could put them in a view.